# How to integrate over a circle in sperical coordinates

Tags: scattering-cross-section

I have an angular distribution $\frac{s \sigma}{d\Omega} = \frac{d\sigma}{d \left(\cos\theta\right) d\phi}$. How can I calculate it over a circle which lies on the plane $X = dist$, has radius $r$ and its centre is located at $P(a,b)$ on this plane?

Edit: All I need to know is what are $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ in the integral $\int^{\cos\theta_2}_{\cos\theta_1}\int^{\phi_2}_{\phi_1}\frac{d\sigma}{d \left(\cos\theta\right) d\phi}d \left(\cos\theta\right) d\phi$.

Comment: What's $s$ and is $d\Omega = d(\theta\phi)$? If so, check that.

Comment: I corrected the formula. I meant $d\Omega = d\theta d\phi$

Comment: I don't think that $d\Omega = d\theta d\phi$. There should be a $\sin\theta$ term in there.  If you integrate your form over all angles you won't get $4\pi$ steradians.

Comment: One thing to note is that if you have a distribution density (*whatever* per steradian) you can't integrate it over a circle.  You can integrate it over a band of some width (like a belt).  The width of that band could approach zero, in which case you would represent it by d$A$.    You'd have to express d$A$ in terms of your coordinate variables, taking into account the orientation of the circle.  Watch out for factors of sin and cos!

Comment: Why can't I integrate it over a circle (at least theoretically)? I don't mean a circle which lays on the sphere (then it isn't a circle anymore). Sorry, I didn't make myself clear: all I need are the boundaries for calculating the integral.